# Как в SimpleCursorAdapter внести 2 значения из одного поля?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Есть метод:

```
//Метод формирования ListView Расходов
private void setupLVtableCost() {
    //Формируем столбцы сопоставления
    String[] from = new String[]{db.COST_TABLE_NAME, db.COST_TABLE_SUMM, db.CURRENCY_TABLE_SHORT_NAME,
            db.CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME, db.WALLET_TABLE_NAME, db.COST_TABLE_DATE};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.cost_lv_item_name, R.id.cost_lv_item_summ, R.id.cost_lv_item_currency,
            R.id.cost_lv_item_cat_name, R.id.cost_lv_item_wallet_name, R.id.cost_lv_item_date};
    // создаем адаптер и настраиваем список
    scAdapterTableCost = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_cost, null, from, to, 0);
    //Привязываем адаптер в Листу
    lvCost.setAdapter(scAdapterTableCost);
    // добавляем контекстное меню к списку
    registerForContextMenu(lvCost);
    // создаем лоадер для чтения данных
    loaderCost = getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(Constants.LOADER_ID_TABEL_COST, null, this);
}
```

он работает тут вопросов нет. Нужно по такому же примеру построить другой список, "переводов". Загвоздка в том что мене нужна информация из одного и того же поля, но для разных кошельков (связанных с другой таблице). Получается надо указывать поля откуда брать инфу и ИД куда вставлять, но поле с именем одно. **Как указать что в первое ИД нужно имя с первого ключа, а втрое со второго?**

```
//В формировании курсора надо заполнить 2 массива - это не работает, как правильно?
String[] from = new String[]{db.WALLET_TABLE_NAME, db.WALLET_TABLE_NAME, db.TRANSFER_TABLE_SUMM, db.CURRENCY_TABLE_SHORT_NAME};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.trans_wall_name_one, R.id.trans_wall_name_sec, R.id.trans_summ, R.id.trans_wall_curr};
```

запрос:

```
select * from transfer t, wallet w1, wallet w2
where t.wall_id_one=w1._id and t.wall_id_sec=w2._id
```

Comment: запрос покажите. судя по описанию, скорее всего вам нужны псевдонимы полей в запросе, которые далее использовать в вашем `from`.

Comment: Добавил запрос, как добраться к псевдонимам?

Comment: надо раскрыть звездочку. псевдонимы задаются непосредственно для конкретных полей `select w1.id as w1id, w2.id as w2id...` и тогда в `String[] from = new String[]{"w1id","w2id"....}`

Comment: запрос в другом классе, в своем методе, как я могу увидеть ПСЕВДОНИМ из другого класса?

Comment: Вы не поняли. "Псевдоним" - это alias имени поля в выборке ([см. здесь](http://www.firststeps.ru/sql/oracle/r.php?29), например). В приведенном мной примере псевдонимы - это **w1id** и **w2id**. Ваш запрос со звездочкой `select *` нужно переписать, указав для каждого вашего поля псевдоним. Иначе SQLite дублирует вам имена столбцов (будет два раза id, два раза name и т.д.), другие субд выдали бы либо ошибку, либо отобразили бы только один столбец, либо придумали бы псевдоним сами типа name_1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем кастомном CursorLoader'е:

```
@Override
public Cursor loadInBackground() {
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
       "select w1.name as name_one, w2.name as name_sec, "
      +"  t.summ, c.name as curr_name "
      +"from transfer t "
      +"  join wallet w1 on t.wall_id_one=w1._id "
      +"  join wallet w2 on t.wall_id_sec=w2._id "
      +"  join currencies c on t.cur_id = c._id", null);
  return cursor;
}
```

Метод настраивающий адаптер (видимо во фрагменте он у вас):

```
void setupLVTransfers(){
    String[] from = new String[]{"name_one", "name_sec", "summ","curr_name"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.trans_wall_name_one, R.id.trans_wall_name_sec, R.id.trans_summ, R.id.trans_wall_curr};
    scAdapterTransfers = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.item_transfer, null, from, to, 0);
    lvTransfers.setAdapter(scAdapterTransfers);
    // etc...
}
```

Названия **name_one**, **name_sec**, **curr_name** называются псевдонимами полей в выборке, с их помощью можно выбирать столбцы из разных таблиц с одинаковыми именами, в выборке имена столбцов будут *переименованы* в псевдонимы. Вы их также можете зашить в константы, если это как-то будет полезно.

Comment: Работает!! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Никак не сделаете в рамках `SimpleCursorAdapter` - он же *Simple*, то есть простой:

> An easy adapter to map columns from a cursor to TextViews or ImageViews defined in an XML file

Пишите свою имплементацию и в методе `bindView()` свяжите те данные которые хотите чтобы адаптер вам показывал.

Это не так сложно, как кажется. Можно просто взять [исходники SimpleCursorAdapter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java#SimpleCursorAdapter) и немного подкрутить их так как вам надо.

Comment: примерно так и думал. спасибо.